# Is it possible to trigger a PHP or BASH script when /dev/ttyUSB0 receives data?

Tags: php, bash, serial-port, usb

I have a device connected to my USB port which transmits information every 16 seconds. the data is in Hexadecimal and looks like this:

```
10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 12 80 07 08 00 05 00 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 b2
```

How could I trigger a BASH or PHP (LAMP is running) when this information comes into my /dev/ttyUSB0 ?

Comment: i would consider neither language ideal for this, you want a server deamon or persistent application

Comment: I have written a program in C that reads/writes to /dev/ttyUSB0 and I may try to use it as a proxy/driver to access the USB. What server daemon or persistent application were you thinking of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be using **libnotify** library. Install **libnotify-tools** package and than run the following script.

```
while true
do    
    inotifywait -e CLOSE /dev/ttyUSB0 && run_the_command
done
```

Comment: Is there a way to use that command to see the output of what what sent? I've tried this so far and it worked:


(root@8012:~# inotifywait -e CLOSE /dev/ttyUSB0 && echo "got datas"
Setting up watches. 
Watches established. 
/dev/ttyUSB0 CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE 
got datas

Comment: Unfortunately inotify will not let you see the data, it will just tell you whether the file has changed.

Comment: is there a way to somehow pipe the data to send it to a php script?